# Changing the scrolling amount of a spark DataGrid when using the mouse wheel

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flex-spark

Basically what the title says. I checked DataGridSkin, and it has a Scroller skin part, but I can't find any attribute for the scrolling amount. I might have missed it.
Can anybody please help me on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Why was this question suddenly voted down? It's a programming question to which I have already found and posted an answer. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I used the idea described above, but instead of creating a class that extends VScrollBar, I added a MouseWheelChanging event listener to the scroll bar in the Scroller skin:

```
<fx:Component id="verticalScrollBarFactory">
        <s:VScrollBar visible="false" mouseWheelChanging="outerDocument.vScrollBarWheelChanging(event)"/>
    </fx:Component>

internal function vScrollBarWheelChanging(event:MouseEvent):void
    { event.delta/=Math.abs(event.delta); }
```

You can set `event.delta` to the desired scroll amount.

Comment: Just some thoughts on mouse wheel stepping. The "step" for the mouse wheel is controlled in the mouse settings on the computer.  For users who have already adjusted this value, they will get a different experience than what you are finding in your testing.  So the "right feel" for scrolling that you have adjusted for, might still be different for other users.

Comment: Thank you, we have a QA department that's responsible for testing such cases.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following. You can find part of scrolling logic in `VScrollBar` class in `mouseWheelHandler` method.

```
var nSteps:uint = Math.abs(delta);
...
for (var vStep:int = 0; vStep < nSteps; vStep++)
        {
            var vspDelta:Number = vp.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(navigationUnit);
...
```

In my case `delta` equals `3`. And grid is scrolled for 3 renderers heights. You can extend VScrollBar class. Then create custom ScrollerSkin (copy from original one) and set you vertical bar there instead of default one. Then create custom `DataGrid` skin (again copy from original one) and set your custom scroller skin for `Scroller` there.

In custom VScrollBar class override `mouseWheelHandler` method. Example:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import mx.core.IInvalidating;

    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.events.FlexMouseEvent;

    import spark.components.VScrollBar;
    import spark.core.IViewport;
    import spark.core.NavigationUnit;
    import spark.utils.MouseEventUtil;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class MyVScrollBar extends VScrollBar {
        public function MyVScrollBar() {

        }

        override mx_internal function mouseWheelHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            const vp:IViewport = viewport;
            if (event.isDefaultPrevented() || !vp || !vp.visible || !visible)
                return;

            var changingEvent:FlexMouseEvent = MouseEventUtil.createMouseWheelChangingEvent(event);
            if (!dispatchEvent(changingEvent))
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }

            const delta:int = changingEvent.delta;
            var nSteps:uint = 1; //number of renderers scrolled!
            var navigationUnit:uint;
            var scrollPositionChanged:Boolean;
            navigationUnit = (delta < 0) ? NavigationUnit.DOWN : NavigationUnit.UP;
            for (var vStep:int = 0; vStep < nSteps; vStep++)
            {
                var vspDelta:Number = vp.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(navigationUnit);
                if (!isNaN(vspDelta))
                {
                    vp.verticalScrollPosition += vspDelta;
                    scrollPositionChanged = true;
                    if (vp is IInvalidating)
                        IInvalidating(vp).validateNow();
                }
            }

            if (scrollPositionChanged)
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Set `nSteps` variable to number of renderers you want to be scrolled. So in this example grid is scrolled by only one item on wheel.

Comment: Sorry, your solution gave me: Illegal override of mouseWheelHandler

Comment: What version of SDK are you using? Please share yhe code of your class http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I changed your solution a bit, and this solved my problem. See the answer I added. Thanks for giving me the right direction.